# need a tutorial for ISA Server 2006 web publishing

Tags: windows, isa-server, web

Anyone could recommend me a document for ISA Server 2006 Web Publishing? I want to learn it step by step and also wants to try Path Mapping feature.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these virtual labs:

http://www.microsoft.com/Forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/virtual-labs.aspx

It's not super in depth. But it will give you a good idea of everything and it's step by step interactive.

Comment: The site is so excellent, cool! I have a related question which deals with detailed settings when I map internal server to external server, appreciated if you could help to review here,

http://serverfault.com/questions/35043/help-to-review-isa-server-2006-web-publish-settings